Set initial text field value to empty in showTimePicker
In showTimerPicker, the initial time you enter is the time occupying the text fields. This is quite irritating as you need to manually delete the times, or press long for focusing both digits.
This is how it looks when opened:

showTimePicker's fields do have an empty mode, where the initial time is presented fadely, and the field itself is empty.
It has the option to hold an empty field, where it presents the initial value:

Is there a way to make this the initial state of the showTimerPicker (empty fields), or, alternatively, focus automatically on all digits when a field is picked?
The following shows focused digits only after a long press. Can I make them focused once the field is pressed?

I have tried to go through the documentation, but there is nothing regarding this option.
